# Xcode: build all the dependent targets when building a framework target

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcodebuild, xcframework

I have an Xcode project with a `Framework A` target.

That target depends on a few other modules, e.g. `SubFramework A` and `SubFramework B`.

When running the Xcodebuild command:

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme SchemeName \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' \
-archivePath './build/SchemeName.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive' \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

I'm getting only the resulting library out, i.e. `SchemeName.framework`. When I then try to bundle it into the application, of course, I cannot compile it as `SubFramework A` and `SubFramework B` are not included.

**Q:**

Is it possible to modify the scheme's build settings, `xcodebuild` command or target settings in order to get the `SubFramework A` and `SubFramework B` as the build output results too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Xcode cannot bundle frameworks within frameworks. If app needs Framework A, which needs SubFramework A and SubFramework B, app must also link SubFramework A and SubFramework B.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Community bot is useless